# $Ax = b$ has a solution for every $b$ if $A$ has a pivot in every row

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

What's the intuition behind this statement?

Why does a pivot in every row mean that $Ax=b$ has a solution for all $b$?

Looking for a proof of some sort.

Comment: I guess that means that $A$ is in row echolon form and has non-zero entries on the diagonal. In that case, if $A$ is $m\times n$ and $m\le n$, the first $m$ columns are linearly independent, which then implies the claim.

Comment: Do you want a proof or do you want an explanation that appeals to your (unknown to us) intuition?

Answer (score 0):

Leading Coefficient is also known as pivot of a matrix in Row echelon form

you can see example in

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient#Linear_algebra

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form

so if we have matrix in row echelon form with all pivots you can back substitute and arrive at a solution